# graphics software that can draw scater plot using vector images instead of points

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, vector-graphics, plotting

Traditionally used graphics software draws scatter plots using points: small circles, squares, diamons, etc.

[image: Scatter plot consisted of points]

But I'd like to use small vector images instead of predefined symbols.

[image: Scatter plot consisted of vector images]

Is there any software that can do this?

**Addons**

I have a set of points each of which represents some features of some object.
Also each object has an image associated with it.

To visualize the distribution of object features, I use a scatter plot. The usual scatter plot shows points, but I want to see the images of objects instead of points.

Whiсh software can do this?

Comment: Different symbol for each point?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: What OS shall it run on? Any limits concerning pricing or license?

Comment: Windows. Free, or less than $50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows (Linux, Mac), free, [OpenSCAD](https://openscad.org/) may provide a solution. It is a text based 3D model creation program that also provides for 2D image generation. One can use import() feature in the software to select any desired SVG file. The location of the imported file would be determined by the translate() feature and can be selected from a manually entered list representing the plotted locations.

Conditionals can be used if desired to select different SVG images.

[image: plotting svg images]

I created the above image in OpenSCAD but used discreet points, rather than using a list, as I lack certain coding skills in OpenSCAD, especially with lists.